# mysql - How do I sort in count descending order, a list that pulls out specific values from a query?

Tags: mysql

so I made a list that I need to sort out based on the total amount of times that a certain value comes out. So below is the table,

```
name  | remark
mary  | has a Samsung phone
peter |  has an Iphone
sam   | has an Iphone
bart  | has a Nokia phone
gary  | has a Samsung phone
may   | has an Iphone
```

So I want to sort it based on the total amount of times that the phone brands were mentioned.
So for example; I want to get the result,

```
name  | remark
may   | has an Iphone
peter |  has an Iphone
sam   | has an Iphone
mary  | has a Samsung phone
gary  | has a Samsung phone
bart  | has a Nokia phone
```

I tried using a LIKE function to see if I could pull out the phone brands but I've been having trouble trying to get the count of the brands and listing it in order. Any idea how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Your sample data doesn't get the point across, because every row of your sample data has exactly one cell phone mentioned.

Comment: Do you have a table with the brands?

Comment: No I don't. I was hoping to use a command to pull out the brands and sort it from there if possible.

Comment: There is no criteria to define what word in the remark is brand name.

Answer (score 1):

You have no `brands` table.. so the rows are sorted by the whole `remark` column value copies amount:

```
SELECT *
FROM test t1
ORDER BY ( SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM test t2
           WHERE t1.remark = t2.remark ) DESC
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f11ed4c883dec97811a417fa0971d0cf)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the format of the `remark` column is consistent, we can sort by the number of occurences of each remark, using window functions:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
order by count(*) over(partition by remark) desc, name
```

Notes:

- window functions are available in MySQL 8.0 only
- I added a second sort criteria, so rows having the same brand are then sorted by `name`

Comment: Would I still be able to use partition if the format in the remark column was inconsistent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi queries see code bellow:

```
    Select dd.name,dd.remark,dd2.cnt from  
    (select  name, remark,0 as cnt from Test group by name,remark) as dd, 
   (select   remark,count(remark) as cnt from Test group by remark) as dd2 where 
    dd.remark=dd2.remark order by dd2.cnt desc ,dd.name
```

**[Code example](https://paiza.io/projects/sLalYaGcZeiaEIIxAcwJtw?language=mysql)**